# How do I delimit a string based on whitespace (tabs or uneven space) into a tuple?

Tags: string, loops, parsing, rust, iterator

I want to read a whitespace-separated file (could be tab or uneven space) into tuples:

```
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead, Cursor};

fn main() {
    let data = "
A       1    Pass
B   2         Fail
C   3       Fail
";
    let lines = BufReader::new(Cursor::new(data))
        .lines();
    for line in lines {
        let line_temp = line.unwrap();
        let broken_line: Vec<&str> = line_temp.split(" ").collect(); // This works
        // I want something like below:
        // let (a, b, c) = ("A", 1, "Pass");
        println!("{:?}", broken_line);
    }
}
```

I want `a` to store the first column, `b` to store second column and so on.

```
a = A, b = 1, c = Pass
a = B, b = 2, c = Fail
// ...
```

Comment: And what's your problem specifically?

Comment: [How to create a tuple from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38863781/155423); [Is there any way to unpack an iterator into a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29504873/155423); [How to generate tuples from strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29618700/155423);

Comment: Right now for me the broken_line in Vec is working. But I want some thing that works with  `lines.par_iter().for_each()` to parrallelise/optimise it.
And also the space is uneven. Hence I am getting lot of `""`

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about parallelism, and that last comments seems to indicate that your problem has nothing to do with tuples, rather "How do I filter empty strings out of an iterator?"?

Comment: okay... Sorry if I am not clear. I know how to do parallelism now, so didnt add that to the question. The problem is when I have uneven space, I cant use a tuple because "" are considered as one element. Based on this I thought I was clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is well-formed (aside from empty lines) and you don't have to worry about validating each individual line then you can do this

```
fn main() {
    let data = "
A       1    Pass
B   2         Fail
C   3       Fail
";
    for line in data.lines() {
        let line = line.trim();
        if line.is_empty() {
            continue;
        }
        let mut parts = line.split_whitespace();
        let tuple = (
            parts.next().unwrap(),
            parts.next().unwrap().parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
            parts.next().unwrap(),
        );
        println!("{:?}", tuple);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f3d6b100684e279b2e752d297777892)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. In my file first line is title line and I have to ignore it. I think I can do with a if condition before let tuple

Comment: @Selva You can skip the first line with `for line in data.lines().skip (1) { … }`